# Json-сервер get запрос

Tags: json

Можно ли запросить с `json-сервера` n-ое количество статей из объекта с заданным id?

То есть из объекта с id = 0 одним запросом получить 2 первых статьи(только их). Такое возможно?

```
{
 id: 0,
 reviews: ["article1", "article2", "article3", "article4"]
}
```

Comment: Что Вы подразумеваете под "json-сервер"? Если это REST API, то зависит от самой API.

Comment: Npm библиотека, эмулирующая запросы на сервер, так и называется.

Comment: А ID  в Вашем случае, это что-то вроде ID автора?

Comment: ID продукта, articles внутри - для него

Comment: Не буду утверждать, но с Вашей реализацие вроде как нельзя, так как это реализовано не как связанные данные, а просто как массив. Можете на клиенте сделать что-то вроде `reviews.slice(0, 2)`.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо

Comment: Что за сервер то? `json` - это формат ответа, а запросы могут быть с какими угодно параметрами, это зависит от реализации конкретного сервера.